# CreatePairedStream is not a member of MQTTUtils

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, spark-streaming, mqtt

When I declared MQTTUTils.createPairedStream() I got an error like

> value createPairedStream is not a member of object org.apache.spark.streaming.mqtt.MQTTUtils

My spark and Scala versions are

SCALA VERSION - 2.11.8

SPARK VERSION - 2.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the following pull request in apache Bahir: [Bahir Pull Request](https://github.com/apache/bahir/pull/37/files/f87c0eb2a4747068d909b911e702f5506a8c3627#diff-ca228f0db33c99a058b5a6c28fa29fca)

Where you can see *MQTTUtils.createPairedStream* being added.

You import in your pom/gradle/sbt... using the following artifact:

**spark-sql-streaming-mqtt_2.11** version **2.3.2** from the group **org.apache.bahir**.

Up to Spark 1.6 you could use in maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-mqtt -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

For Spark 2.3.2, you'll need to use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Or in SBT:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-mqtt" % "2.3.2"
```

You can find further information on: [org.apache.bahir:spark-streaming-mqtt](https://github.com/apache/bahir/tree/master/streaming-mqtt)

```
bin/spark-shell --packages org.apache.bahir:spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11:2.3.0
```

You will import the package using scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.mqtt._
```

and instantiate:

```
val lines = MQTTUtils.createPairedStream(ssc, brokerUrl, topic)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I started the spark-shell using the command 
"bin/spark-shell --packages org.apache.bahir:spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11:2.0.0 --repositories http://central.maven.org/maven2/"

my spark version is 2.3.0 and scala version is 2.11.8 

Does this support only for spark 2.3.2?

Comment: Looks like it is available: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.bahir/spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11/2.3.0

Comment: You can check how to import and instantiate here: https://github.com/apache/bahir/tree/master/streaming-mqtt